# Is it possible to mock Gradle Project methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to write UT for my Gradle plugin. I faced a wall while trying to mock Gradle Project methods. Under the hood, I'm using Gradle Properties to calculate the plugin's extension providers. Example:

```java
this.outputDir = project.getObjects().property(String.class);
this.outputDir.convention(project.provider(() -> {
  if (project.hasProperty("com.example.outputDir")) {
    return project.property("com.example.outputDir").toString();
  }
  return "./default-output";
}));
```

I wanted to write simple tests checking if I provide the `com.example.outputDir` property, it will be returned by the convention. So I figured out, that I will mock `project.hasProperty` and `project.property`:

```java
// Creating Gradle Project on the fly
ProjectBuilder builder = ProjectBuilder.builder();

// Mocking the Project (Project is an interface)
Project testProject = Mockito.spy(builder.build());

// Applying the plugin to the mocked project
testProject.getPlugins().apply(PLUGIN_NAME);

// Enabling mock
when(testProject.hasProperty("com.example.outputDir")).thenReturn(true);

// This works (obviously)
Assertions.assertEquals(true, testProject.hasProperty("com.example.outputDir"));

// This does not work
MyExtension ext = (MyExtension) testProject.getExtensions().getByName("my-extension");
Assertions.assertEquals("hello-world", ext.ouputDir.get());
```

After digging in into IntelliJ debugger, it seems that Gradle is keeping a registry of the projects... So when the extension is created, it's getting a reference to the original project, not mocked one. Which is super weird for me, because I'm using `testProject.getPlugins().apply(PLUGIN_NAME);` so why on earth Gradle would not use a reference of the project that has called the function, and instead it's checking "own source"?

So I'm wondering if is it even possible to test and mock Gradle Projects (and Plugins)? I heard that Gradle is a super popular tool, but there is zero articles/documentation on how to properly test and mock Gradle Plugins.

I would appreciate for any help and guidance in this area.

Comment: _"there is zero articles/documentation on how to properly test and mock Gradle Plugins"_ There is documentation on testing Gradle plugins here: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/testing_gradle_plugins.html

Comment: Sorry, but this documentation is almost useless. There is no information how to mock Gradle projects.